# RecordNotFound: Couldn't find City with id=0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a filter. In my search fields, I have an option called, "all cities", with the value 0.

In the controller, I would like it to ignore the filter if the params[:city_id] = 0

This is what I have written -->

```
@city = City.find(params[:city_id]) if params[:city_id] && params[:city_id] != 0

@jobs = Job.all
@jobs = @jobs.includes(:cities).where(cities: { id: @city }) if @city
```

However, I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in JobsController#index
```

Why would that happen? Shouldn't City.find(params[:city_id]) not fire, because in the if parameter I included that params[:city_id != 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter will be a String in the `params` hash, you need to change the condition to:

```
params[:city_id] != "0"
```

Comment: You. are. AWESOME mechanicalfish! :). Thanks. Will accept answer in 11mins